# Difference between FusedLocationProvider and FusedLocationProviderApi?

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi

*FYI, I'm developing an Xposed module.*

Inspecting Android source code I've found a class named [`FusedLocationProvider`](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/packages/FusedLocation/src/com/android/location/fused/FusedLocationProvider.java)
.

What's the difference between this Location Provider and the Fused Location Provider in Google Play Services, exposed in interface 
[`FusedLocationProviderApi`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)?

Using shell command `dumpsys location`, it also dumps information about providers `gps`, `network` and `fused`.

Also I've discovered that in `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`, it can be used, as `provider` parameter, the string `fused` (defined in `LocationManager`) and receive location updates which seems generated by Fused Location Provider.